# OSM Nominatum encoding for address

Tags: r, encoding, openstreetmap, nominatim

i am using SUNGEO package to geolocate a long list of addresses in Norway.

It says that Nominatum returns addresses in UTF-8 but I am not able to get this variable into proper format....

THis is what I am using and getting:

> data_geocode_full_test<- geocode_osm_batch(test[1:100], delay=5,
> details=TRUE, verbose = TRUE)

The enquiry column looks "normal" but the address is in wrong encoding:

```
> data_geocode_full_test%>%head(20)%>%dput()
structure(list(query = c("LÖVMOVÄGEN 57, Upplands Väsby ", 
"VINTERVÄGEN 155, Upplands Väsby ", "EDS KYRKVÄG 8, Upplands Väsby ", 
"RYTTARGATAN 275, Upplands Väsby ", "KULLAVÄGEN 16, Upplands Väsby ", 
"SUNDSBORGSVÄGEN 113, Upplands Väsby ", "MARIA KRANTZONS VÄG 29, Upplands Väsby ", 
"BROMSBODAVÄGEN 17, Upplands Väsby ", "SKOGSTORPSVÄGEN 1, Upplands Väsby ", 
"SUNDSBORGSVÄGEN 3, Upplands Väsby ", "ARDENNERGATAN 1, Upplands Väsby ", 
"BJÖRNBÄRSVÄGEN 12, Upplands Väsby ", "VIRAVÄGEN 2, Upplands Väsby ", 
"SKATTBONDEVÄGEN 12, Upplands Väsby ", "SADELGATAN 258, Upplands Väsby ", 
"PRÄSTGÅRDSVÄGEN 2, Upplands Väsby ", "RYTTARGATAN 275, Upplands Väsby ", 
"RYTTARGATAN 278, Upplands Väsby ", "HAVREGATAN 9, Upplands Väsby ", 
"RINGBLOMSVÄGEN 11, Upplands Väsby "), osm_id = c("16425688", 
"19116665", "380231557", "6269910286", "126259490", "138200460", 
"575078941", "141851191", "129695763", "137241803", "27640787", 
"16316489", "542508430", "28312101", "126704094", "129556526", 
"6269910286", "550674304", "533260253", "1006514946"), osm_type = c("way", 
"way", "way", "node", "way", "way", "way", "way", "way", "way", 
"way", "way", "way", "way", "way", "way", "node", "way", "way", 
"way"), importance = c(0.40001, 0.40001, 0.50001, 0.4101, 0.4101, 
0.41001, 0.60001, 0.4, 0.50001, 0.41001, 0.5, 0.40001, 0.40001, 
0.4, 0.4101, 0.40001, 0.4101, 0.4, 0.5, 0.40001), address = c("LÃ¶vmovÃ¤gen, SkÃ¶ldnora, BollstanÃ¤s, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 64, Sverige", 
"VintervÃ¤gen, Sjukyrkoberg, Bredden, BollstanÃ¤s, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 64, Sverige", 
"Eds kyrkvÃ¤g, Ed, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 47, Sverige", 
"275, Ryttargatan, Smedby, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 71, Sverige", 
"16, KullavÃ¤gen, Vilunda, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 34, Sverige", 
"113, SundsborgsvÃ¤gen, Sanda, Fresta, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 53, Sverige", 
"Maria Krantzons vÃ¤g, Odenslunda, Vilunda, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 56, Sverige", 
"BromsbodavÃ¤gen, Runby, Skomakarhagen, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 42, Sverige", 
"SkogstorpsvÃ¤gen, Sanda, Fresta, Ekeby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 53, Sverige", 
"3, SundsborgsvÃ¤gen, Sanda, Fresta, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 53, Sverige", 
"Ardennergatan, Odenslunda, Ekebo, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 73, Sverige", 
"BjÃ¶rnbÃ¤rsvÃ¤gen, Bredden, BollstanÃ¤s, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 64, Sverige", 
"ViravÃ¤gen, Brunnby-Vik, Vik, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 51, Sverige", 
"SkattbondevÃ¤gen, Fresta, Ekeby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 53, Sverige", 
"258, Sadelgatan, Ekebo, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 72, Sverige", 
"PrÃ¤stgÃ¥rdsvÃ¤gen, Njursta, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 04, Sverige", 
"275, Ryttargatan, Smedby, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 71, Sverige", 
"Ryttargatan, Bredden VÃ¤st, Smedby, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 72, Sverige", 
"Havregatan, Njursta, PrÃ¤sttorp, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 47, Sverige", 
"RingblomsvÃ¤gen, BollstanÃ¤s, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 64, Sverige"
), longitude = c(17.9459441, 17.9418005, 17.866557, 17.9074389, 
17.9058786449197, 17.94493335, 17.9316469, 17.8876315, 17.9637304, 
17.9459249936174, 17.9177647, 17.93975, 17.9375491, 17.9596357, 
17.9140665488689, 17.8861489, 17.9074389, 17.9129237, 17.8801615, 
17.9535741), latitude = c(59.4952058, 59.5007792, 59.508017, 
59.5076954, 59.51737895, 59.5158072, 59.519685, 59.5247165, 59.5151962, 
59.5128517, 59.5139806, 59.4953153, 59.5339032, 59.518428, 59.50805465, 
59.5136555, 59.5076954, 59.5057079, 59.5151941, 59.5007244), 
    bbox_ymin = c(59.4951003, 59.5006129, 59.5078865, 59.5076454, 
    59.5171918, 59.5157424, 59.5196826, 59.5231604, 59.51496, 
    59.5126555, 59.511177, 59.4946063, 59.5336987, 59.5183616, 
    59.5079014, 59.5125137, 59.5076454, 59.5049557, 59.5143229, 
    59.5007244), bbox_ymax = c(59.4952363, 59.5007792, 59.5081383, 
    59.5077454, 59.5175781, 59.515872, 59.5196877, 59.5269884, 
    59.515843, 59.5131436, 59.5140046, 59.4962885, 59.5344431, 
    59.5192497, 59.5083146, 59.5147537, 59.5077454, 59.5067477, 
    59.5160863, 59.5007715), bbox_xmin = c(17.9456666, 17.9418005, 
    17.8664143, 17.9073889, 17.9054212, 17.9448142, 17.9299932, 
    17.8852799, 17.9633726, 17.9456178, 17.914354, 17.9389514, 
    17.9367699, 17.9579108, 17.9138134, 17.8857297, 17.9073889, 
    17.9102479, 17.8796081, 17.9534576), bbox_xmax = c(17.9460489, 
    17.9418603, 17.8667449, 17.9074889, 17.9063531, 17.9450525, 
    17.9331563, 17.8881643, 17.9641165, 17.9462435, 17.9196486, 
    17.9406962, 17.9380534, 17.960939, 17.9144792, 17.8861489, 
    17.9074889, 17.9152162, 17.8810689, 17.9535741)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried with no luck from past questions: How to fix this?

> data_geocode_full_test$address
> <-as.character(data_geocode_full_test$address)
> Encoding(data_geocode_full_test$address) <- 'UTF-8'

[image]

Comment: Could you display any UTF-8 character? I think the problem is in your console, which just display weirdly (aka as Latin1) the UTF-8 bytes

Comment: Is the result from `jsonlite::fromJSON("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&q=LÖVMOVÄGEN+57,Upplands+Väsby&format=json&limit=1")$display_name`  displayed correctly?  Have you tested other Nominatum client libraries like nominatimlite or tidygeocoder  and had similar issues?

Comment: @margusl yes, jsonlite works well

Answer (score 0):

`dput()` output does not carry encoding details, so this is kind of a guesswork, but if those results were somehow stored in a wrong encoding, perhaps `iconv` **from** utf8 helps to fix this:

```r
# before:
head(data_geocode_full_test$address)
#> [1] "LÃ¶vmovÃ¤gen, SkÃ¶ldnora, BollstanÃ¤s, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 64, Sverige"                
#> [2] "VintervÃ¤gen, Sjukyrkoberg, Bredden, BollstanÃ¤s, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 64, Sverige"     
#> [3] "Eds kyrkvÃ¤g, Ed, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 47, Sverige"                    
#> [4] "275, Ryttargatan, Smedby, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 71, Sverige"            
#> [5] "16, KullavÃ¤gen, Vilunda, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 34, Sverige"            
#> [6] "113, SundsborgsvÃ¤gen, Sanda, Fresta, Upplands VÃ¤sby, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 53, Sverige"

data_geocode_full_test$address <- iconv(data_geocode_full_test$address, from = "UTF-8", to = "latin1") |> `Encoding<-`("UTF-8")
# or:
# data_geocode_full_test$address <- iconv(data_geocode_full_test$address, from = "UTF-8", to = "Windows-1252") |> `Encoding<-`("UTF-8")

# after: 
head(data_geocode_full_test$address)
#> [1] "Lövmovägen, Sköldnora, Bollstanäs, Upplands Väsby kommun, Stockholms län, 194 64, Sverige"                  
#> [2] "Vintervägen, Sjukyrkoberg, Bredden, Bollstanäs, Upplands Väsby kommun, Stockholms län, 194 64, Sverige"     
#> [3] "Eds kyrkväg, Ed, Upplands Väsby, Upplands Väsby kommun, Stockholms län, 194 47, Sverige"                    
#> [4] "275, Ryttargatan, Smedby, Upplands Väsby, Upplands Väsby kommun, Stockholms län, 194 71, Sverige"           
#> [5] "16, Kullavägen, Vilunda, Upplands Väsby, Upplands Väsby kommun, Stockholms län, 194 34, Sverige"            
#> [6] "113, Sundsborgsvägen, Sanda, Fresta, Upplands Väsby, Upplands Väsby kommun, Stockholms län, 194 53, Sverige"
```

Trying to replicate it with an actual request, reading UTF-8 response as latin1 and then fixing the result:

```r
library(httr)
resp_latin1 <- httr::GET("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&q=LÖVMOVÄGEN+57,Upplands+Väsby&format=json&limit=1") |>
  content(as = "text", encoding = "latin1") |>
  jsonlite::fromJSON()
resp_latin1$display_name
#> [1] "LÃ¶vmovÃ¤gen, SkÃ¶ldnora, BollstanÃ¤s, Upplands VÃ¤sby kommun, Stockholms lÃ¤n, 194 64, Sverige"
Encoding(resp_latin1$display_name)
#> [1] "UTF-8"

iconv(resp_latin1$display_name, from = "UTF-8", to = "latin1") |> `Encoding<-`("UTF-8")
#> [1] "Lövmovägen, Sköldnora, Bollstanäs, Upplands Väsby kommun, Stockholms län, 194 64, Sverige"
```

If it doesn't have to be `SUNGEO`, there are also other libraries for querying OSM Nominatum service, e.g. `nominatimlite`:

```r
library(nominatimlite)
address <- c("LÖVMOVÄGEN 57, Upplands Väsby ", "VINTERVÄGEN 155, Upplands Väsby ", 
             "EDS KYRKVÄG 8, Upplands Väsby ", "RYTTARGATAN 275, Upplands Väsby ", 
             "KULLAVÄGEN 16, Upplands Väsby ")
nominatimlite::geo_lite(address)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   query                                lat   lon address                        
#>   <chr>                              <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                          
#> 1 "LÖVMOVÄGEN 57, Upplands Väsby "    59.5  17.9 Lövmovägen, Sköldnora, Bollsta…
#> 2 "VINTERVÄGEN 155, Upplands Väsby "  59.5  17.9 Vintervägen, Sjukyrkoberg, Bre…
#> 3 "EDS KYRKVÄG 8, Upplands Väsby "    59.5  17.9 Eds kyrkväg, Ed, Upplands Väsb…
#> 4 "RYTTARGATAN 275, Upplands Väsby "  59.5  17.9 Upplands Väsbyn ruotsinsuomala…
#> 5 "KULLAVÄGEN 16, Upplands Väsby "    59.5  17.9 16, Kullavägen, Vilunda, Uppla…
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you - i thought there is an way to use the collected 9,000+ records with fixing encoding, rather than collect all of them again...

Comment: @m45ha , fixing encoding issues can be quite tricky, but I added one possible scenario to the answer.